# "user was removed"?

Tags: support, specific-user-account

Checking out today's questions in the CS Stack Exchange,
I noticed my reputation went down by 10 points. Clicking on my name showed "-10 user was removed". Anyone knows what this means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Suresh explained, it means that a user who had voted up your posts had his/her account deleted, and therefore his/her votes were automatically cancelled.  See [this post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it/126471#126471).

I think that the message is confusing, and [some people have the same opinion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation).  Moreover, some people think that [the system should not cancel votes just because the voter had his/her account deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted).

Comment: Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 5):

I noticed a similar thing in mine. My suspicion is that if a user upvotes you, and then they are removed from the system, their upvotes are also removed.

Answer (score 3):

I got this too. I have in the past removed users who are definitely spammers, but have not removed other users. I don't know how to trace this event to its source, though.

Comment: SE employees also sometimes delete users, usually because those users mailed them and requested self-deletion. You can see the user deletion in the history of the mod that performed it on the moderator dashboard, though you might have to set the timescale to "all" to be able to see all the SE employees that have acted on your site at some time.